# How to make response immutable

Tags: android, pagination, response

From api call I get `class ItemsResponse(val items: List<Items>) : PaginationResponse()` where `abstract class PaginationResponse(var pagination: Pagination = Pagination())`. The thing is, PageableResponse and all responses in general shouldn't be mutable. The only place I'm making use of this mutability is when mocking response in Unit tests, something like:

```
val itemsResponse = ItemsResponse(items = itemsList).apply {
    pagination = anyNeededPaginationState
}
```

I want to make `pagination` in `PaginationResponse` immutable, but I can't seem to get how to mock the needed response then. With current mocking method, I get `Val cannot be reassigned` error and I don't know how to mock response without reassigning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass an argument through your sub-class constructor.

```
abstract class PaginationResponse(val pagination: Pagination = Pagination())

class ItemsResponse(val items: List<Items>, pagination = Pagination()) : PaginationResponse(pagination)

val itemsResponse = ItemsResponse(items = itemsList, pagination = anyNeededPaginationState)
```